# Is it possible to overload a function to properly accept any template as template template parameter, up to N arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I know it's impossible to have a single template template parameter that would accept any template.

But I thought it was possible with enough overloads:

```
template <template <typename...> typename> void foo() {}
template <template <auto    ...> typename> void foo() {}
// 2
template <template <auto    , typename...> typename> void foo() {}
template <template <typename, auto    ...> typename> void foo() {}
// 3
template <template <typename, auto    , typename...> typename> void foo() {}
template <template <typename, typename, auto    ...> typename> void foo() {}
template <template <auto    , auto    , typename...> typename> void foo() {}
template <template <auto    , typename, auto    ...> typename> void foo() {}
// ...
// 5 (just a single function for the example)
template <template <typename, typename, typename, typename, auto...> typename> void foo() {}

// A test:

#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    foo<std::vector>();
    foo<std::map>();
}
```

But alas, this doesn't work. E.g. `std::vector` causes ambiguity between `<typename...>` and `<typename, typename, auto...>`.

Getting rid of `...` parameter packs doesn't help, now `std::vector` is an ambiguity between `<typename>` and `<typename, typename>` (because its second parameter has a default argument).

Replacing every pack `X...` with `X, X...` (except on first two overloads) also doesn't help. It works with `std::vector` and `std::map`, but if I try passing `template <int, typename...> struct A {}`, it gets matched against the `<auto, typename, typename...>` overload, because that overload is then unable to pass just one template argument to `A`.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you turn into `void foo(type_identity<..>)` overloads?

Comment: @Jarod42 What would `..` be?

Comment: I wanted to place information in argument, as it allow better tie-breaker... but I don't see how to create a template struct allowing a generic template template parameter :-(